# Executable jar project on netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Why does Netbeans pops up "Select main class for execution" on my maven project? I have tried using diferent plugins, most of them with:

```
<archive>
    <manifest>                                                                           
        <mainClass>com.whatever.MainClass</mainClass>
    </manifest>
</archive>
```

I thought Netbeans would respect my maven conf...

Any ideas?

ps. Netbeans 7.4

Comment: It's because netbeans uses `mvn exec:exec` to run `java -cp ${classpath} ${mainclass}`. It does not run the `jar` directly; it runs exploded. If you permanently set the main class than have a look at `nbactions.xml` it becomes clearer.

Comment: hmmm I see, I don't use netbeans nowadays, and a colleague commited this nbactions.xml to the repo. That is why I have tried to find a way to do that on pom.xml.

Thanks!